# Export server ignores param "width"

Tags: export, highcharts

I want to create server sided images from my charts in order to build reports.
The creation of and saving of the images works fine, but i want to state different values of "width" of the images. My attempts to do this were unfortunately not successful.
I have changed the value of "width" and "scale" but nothing has changed. There is always the same width of the created image.

My $command is:

```
chartExport/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs chartExport/js/highcharts-convert.js  -infile chartExport/js/tmp/test.json -outfile chartExport/js/tmp/test.png -width 1000 -scale 1 -constr Chart
```

How can I change the measurements of the images?

Comment: Have you tried to remove scale? Or change order for width and scale (use width first)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both suggestions but there wasn't any change.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.  You can set the scale in the export Options and set the url in export options to your export server and try calling chart.exportChart() once the chart has rendered.

I think it is a bug within Highcharts that not everything is exported correctly and not all of the exporting parameters work.

Comment: This was maybe the case in February, but not now. PLease use the latest version of the phantom script. See [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js)